# IHttpActionResult Ok for methods with no return

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Ok, this will either be a "can't be done" or it will be easy to answer.
I am fond of using 1 line returns like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordRequestModel model) => Ok(await this.UserProvider.ChangePasswordAsync(model, User.Identity));
```

Looks nice and neat and works well if the method has a return. But if it is a **void** or a **Task**, then I can't do that.
I have to separate it out like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResendConfirmationEmailAsync(ResendConfirmationRequestModel model)
{

    // Execute first
    await this.UserProvider.ResendConfirmationEmailAsync(model.UserId, model.CallbackUrl);

    // Return
    return Ok();
}
```

Naturally that bugs me, I would like to do it like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResendConfirmationEmailAsync(ResendConfirmationRequestModel model) => Ok(await this.UserProvider.ResendConfirmationEmailAsync(model.UserId, model.CallbackUrl));
```

I was looking at creating my own **IHttpActionResult** Ok method but I am not sure if this will work or if it will add additional execution time to my application.
Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned it yourself - you can create an overload for `Ok`.

Below is a complete example. I personally don't think it's more readable with the one-line-return. But it works. And **yes**, it will add some overhead because the solution below uses an `Action` to handle the void method. But it *can be done*... Also, the await await-part shows some code smell.

For clarity I called my methods `MyOk` instead of actually overriding `Ok`.

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoStuffWithTask() => await MyOk(async () => await FooWithTask());

    //[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoStuffWithVoid() => await MyOk(() => FooWithVoid());

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoAsync()
    {
        return await MyOk(FooWithTask());
    }


    private async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyOk(Task task)
    {
        await task;
        return Ok();
    }

    private async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyOk(Action stuff)
    {
        stuff();
        return Ok();
    }

    public void FooWithVoid()
    {
        // Do Stuff!
    }

    public async Task FooWithTask()
    {
        // Do Stuff!
        return;
    }
}
```

And with your code:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResendConfirmationEmailAsync(ResendConfirmationRequestModel model) => await MyOk(async () => await this.UserProvider.ResendConfirmationEmailAsync(model.UserId, model.CallbackUrl));
```

Comment: Any idea how much overhead there will be? Is it negligible??

Comment: @r3plica - Sorry mate, I have no idéa about the actual overhead. I _guess_ that the `Action` will generate a `Delegate`. And the duplicate `await` might be more efficient with [tail call-optimization](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1981).

Answer (score 0):

The `=>` starts a C# 6.0 [expression bodied function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx). That means you'll need an expression on the right side of the `=>`. Your method body has multiple statements. Since you can't turn this block of statements into an expression, you can't create an *expression* bodied function.